# Create a gallery using UICollectionView iOS

Tags: ios, image, uitabbarcontroller, gallery, uicollectionview

I wanna create a gallery using uicollectionview above tab bar controller. the problem that i have is i’m getting a SIGABRT crash when i’m connecting uicollectionview datasource. but when i didnt connecting it, the controller view did not show any image. did somebody know what to do?

this is the code I've made :

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"stiker : %d", stickers1.count);
    return stickers1.count;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    NSLog(@"indexpath row : %d", indexPath.row);

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[stickers1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];

    return cell;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInCollectionView coll : %d, stic : %d", collectionView.numberOfSections, stickers1Collection.numberOfSections);

    return collectionView.numberOfSections;
}
```

I've connected the uicollectionview datasource in xib

Comment: Show your code for data source methods.

Comment: What is this log printing `NSLog(@"stiker : %d", stickers1.count);`?

Comment: I just wanna check the image count, it can be deny

Answer (score 1):

**Set number of items**

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

**set content** 
Just add `UIImageView` and `UIlabel` and set there tags in storyboard assign data in  `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *ImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
ImageView.image  = [UIImage imageNamed:[[arrCategoryValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];

UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
lbl.text = [[arrCategoryValue objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

cell.tag = indexPath.row;
return cell;
}
```

for more info you can go [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html)